# scrape google DOMNodelist always empty

Tags: xpath

I want to scrape google search result for collecting IMDB url. everytime i do xpath query using `//ol[@id="rso"]//li[@class="g"]` the DOMNodelist is empty, nothing returned. debug using var_dump the result is `object(DOMNodeList)#38 (0) {
}`. below is the script

```
function crawlIMDB($vtitle, $vid){
    $vtitle .= ' imdb';
    $vtitle = urlencode($vtitle);
    $plus = str_replace('%20', '+', $vtitle);
    $url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='.$vtitle.'&gws_rd=ssl#q='.$plus;
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($response);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $entries = $xpath->query('//ol[@id="rso"]//li[@class="g"]');
    die(var_dump($entries));
}
```

when i try to debug the query using chrome extension, XPath Helper, the query look just fine, result is returned.

the DOM i look for

```
<ol id="rso">
  <div class="srg">
  <li class="g"></li>
  </div>
</ol>
```

Comment: Why don't you scrape the RSS from the IMDB watchlist? Wouldn't it be simpler?

Comment: `vtitle` is video title from youtube, from that title i want to get the IMDB link and then scrape from that link. the problem is youtube video title sometimes really messy, like `MOVIE NAME 1994 (FULL MOVIE) (HD)`, i believe IMDB won't understand that, therefore i use google.

Answer (score 0):

i will answer my own question.

google send different response when i use CURL, so the DOM have different structure. this xpath query should work for collecting links from google search result.

`//h3[@class="r"]/a`

hope this help. thanks